# Deleting ComboBox SelectedItem from Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I am brand new to basically all of this and am trying to learn C# in the context of MVVM. This will be a simple CRUD program and right now I am stuck on the deletion of a `ComboBox`'s `SelectedItem` from the corresponding collection.

Relevant ViewModel code:

```
public class AlbumViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<AlbumModel> albums;

    public AlbumViewModel()
    {
        this.albums = new ObservableCollection<AlbumModel>();
        LoadAlbums();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<AlbumModel> Albums
    { 
        get { return this.albums; }
    }

    public void LoadAlbums()
    {
        albums.Add(new AlbumModel("No Love/Deep Web", "Death Grips"));
        albums.Add(new AlbumModel("In Defense of the Genre", "Say Anything"));
        albums.Add(new AlbumModel("Picaresque", "The Decemberists"));
        albums.Add(new AlbumModel("In Evening Air", "Future Islands"));
        albums.Add(new AlbumModel("You're Gonna Miss It All", "Modern Baseball"));
    }

    #region RelayCommand
    private RelayCommand _deleteCommand;

    public ICommand DeleteCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_deleteCommand == null)
            {
                _deleteCommand = new RelayCommand(param => DeleteItem());
            }

            return _deleteCommand;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region DeleteItem()
    private AlbumModel SelectedItem { get; set; }

    private void DeleteItem()
    {
        if (SelectedItem != null)
        {
            this.albums.Remove(SelectedItem);
            this.SelectedItem = null;
        }
    }
    #endregion


}
```

Relevant Model code:

```
public class AlbumModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion

    // AlbumModel members, properties, constructor
}

#region RelayCommand
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    // fields
    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    // ctors
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {

    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    // ICommand members
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
```

Relevant XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="AlbumsCRUD2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AlbumsCRUD2.ViewModels"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:AlbumViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <local:AlbumViewModel x:Key="albums" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
<GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Header="View Existing">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Album" />

            <ComboBox Name="albumComboBox" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Albums}" 
                      DisplayMemberPath="AlbumName" 
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

            <Label Content="Artist" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=albumComboBox, Path=SelectedItem.ArtistName}" 
                     IsEnabled="False" />

            <Button Name="deleteBtn" Width="100" Margin="30"
                    Command="{Binding DeleteItem}"
                    Content="Delete" />
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

And, of course, the errors in Output:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'SelectedItem' property not found on 'object' ''AlbumViewModel' (HashCode=12507741)'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItem; DataItem='AlbumViewModel' (HashCode=12507741); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name='albumComboBox'); target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'DeleteItem' property not found on 'object' ''AlbumViewModel' (HashCode=12507741)'. BindingExpression:Path=DeleteItem; DataItem='AlbumViewModel' (HashCode=12507741); target element is 'Button' (Name='deleteBtn'); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
```

I suspect it's an error with my data bindings, but I'm having a hard time deciphering the meaning of the errors. I would appreciate any perspective on what is going wrong!

Comment: And what is with the duplicate VM instances, one in the resources one as DataContext?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `SelectedItem` should be public. Bindings need this.
2. You try to bind to the method (`DeleteItem`), not the command (`DeleteCommand`).

Comment: Thank you! They seem like such simple things so it's embarrassing to overlook, but like I said, I'm brand new to this entire concept and learning it is a process. Could you elaborate on what you mean by "view-first" in your previous comment? And the duplicate VM? It would really help.

Comment: You have VM instances in both `Window.DataContext` and `Window.Resources`. There should only be one in `DataContext`, or you create one in resources and reference it in `DataContext` later. View-first means, that you create the view model in the view as you did (twice). As i see it it's a bad approach that WPF is prepared to deal with properly in all cases. The alternative is view-model-first. Search google or stack-overflow for more information.

Comment: @korina: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763072/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-view-first-vs-viewmodel-first-in-the-mvvm-pattern